# Mapping a number to an N dimensional grid/array

Tags: java, math, discrete-mathematics

Lets assume, for example, that I have a 3-dimensional grid/array where the axis run from 1 to 1000 (or 0 to 999 equivalently). This array has 1000^3 elements.

I would like to map a single integer in the range 0 to 1000^3 to this array in a deterministic way using Java. Preferably this solution would work for any dimension N.

Here is a pseudo-codish example of such a function:

```
public Vector<int> nthElement( Vector<int> dims, int n )
```

So if I would call it like `nthElement([1000, 1000, 1000], 0)` it would return `[0, 0, 0]` whereas `nthElement([1000, 1000, 1000], 1001)` would return something like `[999, 1, 0]`.

The solution should be for N dimensions and not for 3 as in my example.

Comment: I think 1001 should be [0,2,1], why 999,1,0?

Comment: @Saeed The specific order of the elements doesn't really matter as long as it's deterministic. I was thinking that the first 1000 numbers would map to [0, 0, 0] to [999, 0, 0] and therefore 1001 would be [999, 1, 0] but as I said, the order doesn't really matter.

Comment: If [999, 0, 0] is 1000, than [0, 1, 0] would be 1001 ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
List<Integer> nthElement( List<Integer> dims, int n ){
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>(dims.size());
    for(Integer cur  : dims){
        if(n <= 0 ){
            res.add(0);
        } else {
            n -= cur;
            res.add(n >= 0 ? cur -1  : cur + n );
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

upd
examples of usage

```
    //create list with 3 dimensions using Guava
    List<Integer> dims = ImmutableList.of(1000, 1000, 1000);
    //or with standard JDK
    //List<Integer> dims = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);dims.add(1000);dims.add(1000);dims.add(1000);

    System.out.println(nthElement(dims, 0));
    System.out.println(nthElement(dims, 1000));
    System.out.println(nthElement(dims, 1001));
    System.out.println(nthElement(dims, 2001));
```

will print

```
    [0, 0, 0]
    [999, 0, 0]
    [999, 1, 0]
    [999, 999, 1]
```

Comment: @lhahne, you can simply change `List` to `Vector` if you need.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin What is this function supposed to do? It doesn't make any sense to me. You add n as the first element in res, then n minus the first item from dims...

Comment: @Alin Purcaru, it just works as @lhahne wants. Of course, nobody will use it in a production)

Comment: @Stas Kurilin I seriously doubt that. Could you test it and provide a sample input/output? (I'm not a Java person so I prefer not to test it myself.)

Comment: @Alin Purcaru, I added some examples of usage. But HOW it works - it's black magic (not best practice).

Comment: @Alin Purcaru, I added some syntax comments

Comment: @Stas Kurilin "upd2 some syntax doc for @Alin Purcaru n -= cur; means n = n - cur"... Oh, come on... :|. You actually thought I don't know some basic operators? They're present in almost all programming languages. As for the algorithm... You may be right... It suits his example. But I don't think this is what he really needs because he asked for a mapping for all numbers until 1000^3, not until 1000*3.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru, upd2 removed. I don't know PHP at all so.. About algorithm, I think you can be right.. Let's waite @lhahne)

Answer (score 3):

**This is the correct mapping algorithm:**

```
map([X, Y, Z, T, ...], N) = [
    N mod X, 
    N div X mod Y, 
    N div X div Y mod Z, 
    N div X div Y div Z (mod ...)?
    ...
]
```

or recursive

```
map([X, Y, Z, T, ...], N) = [N mod X, map([Y, Z, T, ...], N div X)]
```

*Where A div B is Floor(A/B).*

Comment: @lhahne I posted a different answer as the first one was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
a = Number % (1000 * 1000)
b = (Number / 1000) % 1000
c = Number / (1000 * 1000)
```

It's a mapping (unique), and you can simply do reverse

note 2/3 = 0 not .6666

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is the [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function). It is defined for NxN, so you can use it for arbitrarily large dimensions. As mentioned on the wikipedia page it can be inductively generalized to an array of dimension n, in your case n=3 works just fine.

The above page also explains inverting the function, so you can get your coordinates in the array from the given number, which is exactly what you want with `nthElement`.

Of course, Cantor has only defined one possible way to walk through a two-dimensional field. There are other possible walks, but this one is the most popular way to do it.

Edit: I should mention, that if your array has rectangular dimensions the Cantor pairing function would assume dimensions of the largest kind. So the associated numbers are no longer successively within your array. F.ex. an array of size 1000x2 would be treated as a 1000x1000 array and the numbers corresponding to entries in your actual array would only be a non-successive list of the numbers 0..1000*1000. 
If, however, your three dimensions are always the same, then this point can be totally ignored.

In response to the comment: Row-by-row and Cantor pairing are just different ways to walk through your matrix space. An advantage of Cantor pairing is that it is defined over the natural numbers and hence also is applicable if you do not have exact values for your matrix dimensions, or your matrix grows over time.

Comment: What is the advantage of Cantor pairing on simple linear row-by-row pairing? (by this I mean start at the bottom row, 0 -> (N-1), then the next row N -> (2N-1) etc. Generalizing to 3 dimensional space, you'd go row by row on one plane, then continue in the same manner on the next plane, like @saeed's answer.